# Have any way to use MySQL as a installable process in PC?

Tags: mysql, electron

I'm looking for a way to after install my electron app install also this "local database" but I don't want to use xampp... Have another way ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't a great choice for this use case -- it's meant to be used in a server environment, not as part of a desktop application. Additionally, distributing it with an application will require you to either distribute your application's source code under the GPL, or pay licensing fees.

A better choice would be SQLite. It's designed for embedding -- in fact, you're probably using an application which embeds it right now! -- and its code is in the public domain, so there are no special licensing requirements. You can use it in an Electron app by installing the [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) Node module.

Comment: Thanks man, i'll try to use it again. I'd tried to use a month ago, but don't worked. And more... A lot of people says that sqlite is not very good for some things that MySQL do very good like inner join and foreign keys... Or am I wrong ?